# Enviar um textarea ao pressionar enter com JS?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Eu to tendo problemas na minha aplicação porque eu possuo dois tipos de textarea na mesma página. Um cria o post e o outro cria o comentário desse post.

O seguinte código faz o envio do textarea da postagem:

```
document.onkeyup=function(e){
     if(e.which == 13){
        if(document.getElementById('textarea-post').value == ""){
        } else {
            document.enviaPost.submit();
        }
      }
 }
```

Formulário do código acima:

```
 <form action="posta.php" method="post" name="enviaPost">
    <ul class="form-post" >
       <li>
          <input type="hidden" name="data" value="<?= date("Y/m/d") ?>" />
          <textarea  placeholder="Como você está se sentindo?" name="contpost" id="textarea-post" /></textarea>
      </li>
          <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="botao-enviar-post" />
  </ul>
```

O que eu gostaria de saber é se, se eu colocar outra keyup como essa pro textarea do comentário, irá causar algum conflito. E caso dê, gostaria de saber como dá pra fazer isso sem gerar um conflito.

Segundo textarea:

```
<form  action="init/add_coment.php" method="post" name="enviaComent">
  <input type="hidden" value="<?=$post['id']?>" name="id_post" />
  <textarea id="texto_coment" name="comentario" class="comentario-texto" placeholder="Escreva um comentário..."></textarea> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lembre-se de adicionar a biblioteca JQuery em sua página

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Este código vai enviar o formulário enviaPost

```
$('#textarea-post').keydown(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            this.form.submit();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Faça a mesma coisa no formulário enviaComent

```
$('#texto_coment').keydown(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            this.form.submit();
        return false;
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1h3dr7nt/

Comment: Não funcionou Lucas :/

Comment: Adicionou o jquery?
O ideal é que ele esteja ao final do código html da página, antes de fechar o </body> para que o usuário não tenha que aguardar o carregamento dele para mostrar o conteúdo da página e logo abaixo do jquery você abrirá <script> e colocará os 2 códigos que postei e fechar </script>. abra o dev tools(ctrl+shift+i) vá na aba Console e se tiver algum erro poste aqui

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado! Só movi a importação pro final da página e deu tudo certo.

Comment: Eu tive um problema aqui... Na minha página existe um form para cada post. Assim, com o código do script acima, ele somente o primeiro comentário está funcionando.. Os demais não estão :/ Como posso fazer pra identificar cada textarea e cada form?

Comment: Desculpe a demora, em todos os textarea que você colocar o id="textarea-post" ou id="texto_coment" vai funcionar com o exemplo acima.